# Oauth is installed but not working

Tags: 14.04, php, oauth

I have installed `ouath` but it is not appearing on `phpinfo` So that i checked following things:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path

```
/opt/lampp/etc
```

Loaded Configuration File

```
/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

`php -m` => When i type this oAuth appears

`/opt/lampp/bin/php -m` => When i type this oAuth doesn't appears and getting an error which says:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/oauth.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/oauth.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

when i checked `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226`  there was no `oauth.so`

but when i checked `/usr/lib/php5/20121212`   there was `oauth.so`

i did a symlinking before installing oauth by using this command

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

i think this might have happend due to symlinking. how do i make oath appear on phpinfo.

i want it to appear when i type `/opt/lampp/bin/php -m` .

any kind of help will apprecaited